# Adding a modules functions automatically to a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, reference, module

Here is a concrete description of what I am trying to do:
I want to add custom filters to the jinja2 template rendering engine. To do this, I need to add references to functions to a dict, like

```
def my_filter(foo):
    do_stuff
    return bar

templateEnv.filters['my_filter'] = my_filter
```

Now in order to make things more generic, I want to have all custom filters in one file (filters.py) and automatically add all those functions to my filter dict. Something like this naive implementation:

```
import filters
for f in all_function_refs_in(filters):
   templateEnv.filters[f.name] = f
```

What I have been able to get is a list of all the names that I want to add:

```
[f for f in  dir(filters) if not f.startswith('__')]
```

But this is just the names, and not a reference to the functions I am trying to add. Is there a way to convert strings back to a function reference? I could probably use 'eval()', but then still I have to get that together with importing the function. Can someone enlighten me on how this could be acomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few options.  The first is to take what you have and use `getattr`:

```
{f: getattr(filters, f) for f in dir(filters) if not f.startswith('__')}
```

But, this can probably be a little easier.  Modules have a `__dict__` attribute which you can look at.  e.g.:

```
print filters.__dict__
```

You could more easily filter that dictionary:

```
{name: func for name, func in filters.__dict__.items() if not name.startswith('__')}
```

Finally, you could use `inspect`:

```
import inspect
{name: func 
 for name, func in inspect.getmembers(filters, inspect.isfunction)
 if not name.startswith('__')}
```